# iOS: How to add NSMutableDictionary to particular index of NSMutableArray in swift?

Tags: ios, swift3

In my existing project was developed by someone in swift 2, I have two NSMutableArrays with a collection of NSDictionarys, NSArray names are array1 and array2. Here is My question, how to add a particular index dictionary from array2 to particular index in array1 as a dictionary.

Here I post the Main Dictionary.

```
{
    AccountNumber = "2004-001-014";
    City = "CANOGA PARK";
    FIPS = 6037;
    InspectionId = 228;
    InspectionLogId = 169;
    InspectionType = "Property Owner";
    InspectionTypeId = 1;
    LandUseCode = 1001;
    ScheduledDate = "2018-02-15T00:00:00";
    State = CA;
    Status = Completed;
    StatusId = 3;
    StreetName = MAYNARD;
    StreetNumber = 8312;
    TemplateId = 1090;
    TemplateName = "Casualty Loss Inspection";
    UserId = 72;
    UserPropertyId = 1380;
    XCoordinate = "34.2197";
    YCoordinate = "-118.6214";
    Zip = 91304;
}
```

Here I post the New Dictionary.

```
LandUseCode = 101;
ScheduledDate = "2018-01-21T00:00:00";
State = CA;
Status = Done;
StatusId = 2;
StreetName = MAYNARD;
StreetNumber = 8312;
TemplateId = 1090;
```

This is the format want to make now.

```
{
    AccountNumber = "2004-001-014";
    City = "CANOGA PARK";
    FIPS = 6037;
    InspectionId = 228;
    InspectionLogId = 169;
    InspectionType = "Property Owner";
    InspectionTypeId = 1;
    LandUseCode = 1001;
    ScheduledDate = "2018-02-15T00:00:00";
    State = CA;
    Status = Completed;
    StatusId = 3;
    StreetName = MAYNARD;
    StreetNumber = 8312;
    TemplateId = 1090;
    TemplateName = "Casualty Loss Inspection";
    UserId = 72;
    UserPropertyId = 1380;
    XCoordinate = "34.2197";
    YCoordinate = "-118.6214";
    Zip = 91304;
    newlyadded =         {
        LandUseCode = 101;
        ScheduledDate = "2018-01-21T00:00:00";
        State = CA;
        Status = Done;
        StatusId = 2;
        StreetName = MAYNARD;
        StreetNumber = 8312;
        TemplateId = 1090;

    };
}
```

But I don't know that.

Here I post the code what I am trying.

```
func mergeOrderAndOpenOrderArrayData() {
        for k in 0..<(logOrderMutArray.count) {
            for j in 0..<self.openOrderArray.count {
                if let logOrderfips:NSNumber = (logOrderMutArray[k] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "FIPS") as? NSNumber {
                    if let openOrderfips:NSNumber = (openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "FIPS") as? NSNumber {
                        if let logOrderAccNum:String = (logOrderMutArray[k] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "AccountNumber") as? String {
                            if let openOrderAccNum:String = (openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "AccountNumber") as? String {
                                if logOrderfips == openOrderfips && logOrderAccNum == openOrderAccNum {
                                    print("Same")
                                    let PropertyMutableDict = NSMutableDictionary()
                                    PropertyMutableDict.setValue((openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "AccountNumber"), forKey: "AccountNumber")
                                    PropertyMutableDict.setValue((openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "FIPS"), forKey: "FIPS")
                                    PropertyMutableDict.setValue((openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "City"), forKey: "City")
                                    PropertyMutableDict.setValue((openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "InspectionId"), forKey: "InspectionId")
                                    PropertyMutableDict.setValue((openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "InspectionLogId"), forKey: "InspectionLogId")
                                    PropertyMutableDict.setValue((openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "InspectionType"), forKey: "InspectionType")
                                    PropertyMutableDict.setValue((openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "InspectionTypeId"), forKey: "InspectionTypeId")
                                    PropertyMutableDict.setValue((openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "LandUseCode"), forKey: "LandUseCode")
                                    PropertyMutableDict.setValue((openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "ScheduledDate"), forKey: "ScheduledDate")
                                    PropertyMutableDict.setValue((openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "State"), forKey: "State")
                                    PropertyMutableDict.setValue((openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "Status"), forKey: "Status")
                                    PropertyMutableDict.setValue((openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "StatusId"), forKey: "StatusId")
                                    PropertyMutableDict.setValue((openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "StreetName"), forKey: "StreetName")
                                    PropertyMutableDict.setValue((openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "StreetNumber"), forKey: "StreetNumber")
                                    PropertyMutableDict.setValue((openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "TemplateId"), forKey: "TemplateId")
                                    PropertyMutableDict.setValue((openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "TemplateName"), forKey: "TemplateName")
                                    PropertyMutableDict.setValue((openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "UserId"), forKey: "UserId")
                                    PropertyMutableDict.setValue((openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "UserPropertyId"), forKey: "UserPropertyId")
                                    PropertyMutableDict.setValue((openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "XCoordinate"), forKey: "XCoordinate")
                                    PropertyMutableDict.setValue((openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "YCoordinate"), forKey: "YCoordinate")
                                    PropertyMutableDict.setValue((openOrderArray[j] as AnyObject).value(forKey: "Zip"), forKey: "Zip")
                                    validatePropertyMutableDict.setValue(PropertyMutableDict, forKey: "validateproperty")
                                    print("validatePropertyMutableDict is", validatePropertyMutableDict)
                                    validatePropertyMutArray.insert(validatePropertyMutableDict, at: k)
                                    print(logOrderMutArray)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: These are the dictionaries, not arrays.

Comment: Note that end result you want is actually a nested dictionary i.e parent dictionary's key contain another dictionary. These are not arrays

Comment: You need to show some code, but if you really have `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` then you can't make changes directly since they are immutable objects.  You will need to make mutable copies and update those.  Honestly, though, if you are writing in Swift you shouldn't have NS Anything unless it can't be avoided.  You should use Swift types.

Comment: This dictionary was particular index of array. (i.e) arra1[0] and next is array2[0]..@AnkitJayaswal

Comment: For this array should have the desired index capacity otherwise you will get index beyond bound crash. After that just `array1[index] = value` will work. ***Note:** array should be an `NSMutableArray` not `NSArray`*.

Comment: Why aren't you using Swift collections? Don't use the `NSxxx` classes in Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the value from existing dictionary append new `dictionary` into this and put it back to its position.

```
var dictMutableCopy = (array1[index] as! NSDictionary).mutableCopy as! NSMutableDictionary
let newDict = array2[index] as! NSDictionary
dictMutableCopy["newlyAdded"] = newDict
/// Or use below line if you want to merge both dictionaries
/// dictMutableCopy.addEntries(from: <#T##[AnyHashable : Any]#>)

array1[index] = dictMutableCopy
```

I don't have `Swift 2.0` environment to test it as it is very old but it will work or help you. You don't need to add one by one key into another dictionary.